# Get path of a given Finder window on MacOS programmatically

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

When the mouse cursor moves from my application's window over any Finder window that may be open, how do I get in my application the current folder which is opened in that Finder window?

My application runs on both Windows and MacOS, but I have only found an answer on Stack Overflow for the Windows case, and don't know how to achieve this for Mac as well.

Comment: AppleScript will talk to the Finder, but I'm not sure how you're going to identify the right window.  Down / close votes a little mean, IMO.

Comment: I added more detail. Please vote to reopen. Equivalent questions exist for the Windows case and were answered instead of closed, so this is more than just a little mean.

Comment: This seems to do similar if not identical? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551419/listing-all-windows-of-all-applications#14552852