# AppleScript - how to close "Your computer was restarted because of a problem" popup?

Tags: macos, applescript

How to close the "Your computer was restarted because of a problem" popup in AppleScript?
[image]

We use a VM to execute e2e tests and they often fail because of this popup. I would like to programmatically close it.

I tried listing the windows based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196136, but the popup is not included in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Diagnostics Reporter"
        if (exists window 1) then click button "Ignore" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33713069)

Comment: This is the complete answer.